# Openlayers 6.4 how to fire select event on every click on the same feature?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, openlayers, openlayers-6

See the code in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-openlayers-reselect-v09n2?file=/src/MyMap.js), There are several overlapping icons.

I can click on the icon, and get a of all the overlapping features.

But if I click again on the same icon, no more events are generated.

I could deselect by clicking away, but this is not what I need.

How do I make the `on('select'` fire on each click?

The reason why I want to do that, is that I have a counter that chooses different feature on each click. Which is possible on google maps, but I can't figure it out on openlayers.

Comment: You cannot select features which are already selected.  If you want more control over what happens when you click on features use the map click event and `forEachFeatureAtPixel` similar to  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-multiple-features.html

Comment: Thanks @Mike that solved it. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-openlayers-reselect-v09n2?file=/src/MyMap.js